# m: command not found

Tags: command-line, make

just tried to compile the R-language from sources but my make aborted with

```
m -f liblzma.a
make[4]: m: Command not found
```

I eagerly searched the web but it seams it's impossible to find the command line tool that has only one letter.. maybe I just lost my searching abilities :/

Maybe someone can give me a hint on that.

EDIT: 
System: SLES 11.4

Thanks!

Comment: You could do `grep -r "\<m -f" .` in the source directory.  I'll guess, this is a typo and someone intended to write `rm` instead of `m`.

Comment: What distribution? And why are you not using your distribution's binary packages?

Comment: Seems to be a known bug that was fixed already: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16755

Comment: to add to @FaheemMitha 's comment, see https://software.opensuse.org/package/R-base and https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/suse/README.html - it's rarely a good idea to compile your own binaries when a package exists for your distro.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was due to an upstream bug that has since been fixed.